# C#, Can I check on a lock without trying to acquire it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a lock in my c# web app that prevents users from running the update script once it has started.

I was thinking I would put a notification in my master page to let the user know that the data isn't all there yet.

Currently I do my locking like so.

```
protected void butRefreshData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(UpdateDatabase));
    t.Start(this);
    //sleep for a bit to ensure that javascript has a chance to get rendered
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}


public static void UpdateDatabase(object con)
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(myLock))
    {
        Updater.RepopulateDatabase();
        Monitor.Exit(myLock);
    }
    else
    {
        Common.RegisterStartupScript(con, AlreadyLockedJavaScript);
    }
}
```

And I do not want to do

```
if(Monitor.TryEnter(myLock))
    Monitor.Exit(myLock);
else
    //show processing labal
```

As I imagine there is a slight possibility that it might display the notification when it isn't actually running.

Is there an alternative I can use?

Edit:
Hi Everyone, thanks a lot for your suggestions! Unfortunately I couldn't quite get them to work... 
However I combined the ideas on 2 answers and came up with my own solution. It seems to be working so far but I have to wait for the process to complete...

Ok this seems to be working, I broke out the Repopule Method into it's own class.

```
public static class DataPopulation
{
    public static bool IsUpdating = false;
    private static string myLock = "My Lock";
    private static string LockMessage = @"Sorry, the data repopulation process is already running and cannot be stopped. Please try again later. If the graphs are not slowly filling with data please contact your IT support specialist.";
    private static string LockJavaScript = @"alert('" + LockMessage + @"');";
    public static void Repopulate(object con)
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(myLock))
        {
            IsUpdating = true;
            MyProjectRepopulate.MyProjectRepopulate.RepopulateDatabase();
            IsUpdating = false;
            Monitor.Exit(myLock);
        }
        else
        {
            Common.RegisterStartupScript(con, LockJavaScript);
        }
    }
}
```

In master I do

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DataPopulation.IsUpdating)
        lblRefresh.Visible = true;
    else
        lblRefresh.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I think I'll move the `IsUpdating = false;` before the `Monitor.Exit(myLock);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just setting a volaltile bool property somewhere that indicates an active lock, perhaps via callback method?

Comment: Although somewhat unlikely, this could in theory still mess up and run the script twice, since you aren't atomically reading and setting the variable.

Comment: Which is why my variation locks around the property instead.  Though Reed makes a valid point in claiming it isn't really better than the OP's race condition the OP was concerned about.

Comment: I have a static bool on my static Repopulate class, we'll see if it turns out.

Comment: @Thorarin: Maybe he could fix that with [`Interlocked.Exchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.exchange.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

(Given that you are aware of the race condition for displaying this notification just after processing stopped.... )

You could switch to a [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx).  This works similarly to a `ManualResetEvent`, but also provides [CurrentCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.currentcount.aspx) and [IsSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.isset.aspx) properies, which could be used to determine if something is being processed.

Comment: CountdownEvent - haven't heard of it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Explore Autoresetevents and ManualResetevents. You can have the spawned thread set the event and check the event in the main thread to display the message.

Comment: There isn't a way to check either of these classes, without actually waiting on them.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

```
butRefreshData_Click()
{
    lock(myLock)
    {
        if (isbusy) {/*tell user*/}
    }
}

UpdateDatabase(object con)
{
    lock(myLock)
    {
        if (isbusy) {/*tell user*/ return;}
        else {isbusy = true;}
    }

    Updater.RepopulateDatabase();

    lock(myLock)
    {
        isBusy = false;
    }
}
```

Note: You should probably wrap `UpdateDatabase` in a try-finally to avoid `isBusy` from being stuck true if an exception is thrown.

Comment: This is, effectively, identical to the Monitor.TryEnter/Monitor.Exit solution the OP is trying to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

> As I imagine there is a slight
>   possibility that it might display the
>   notification when it isn't actually
>   running.

There will always be the possibility you send the "Working..." message and then immediately the job is finished.  What you have should logically work.

```
public static void UpdateDatabase(object con) 
{ 
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(myLock)) 
    {
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Doing the work");
        Thread.Sleep(5000); 
        Monitor.Exit(myLock);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Done doing the work");
    } 
    else 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Entrance was blocked");
    } 
}
```

Comment: -1: This is exactly the opposite of what the OP is trying to do.  Now the window for the race condition is 5000ms + ε instead of ε (where ε is some number that I assume is rather small).